# When I check the version of rails after installing ruby on rails I get this message:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/todo/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle pack
bundle install --path vendor/cache
```